# Hide/Show all objects in a NSWindow - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, object, nswindow, show-hide

Quick question. How can I hide and then show all the objects in a NSWindow without doing something terribly tedious and complicated?

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be late to this particular party, but how about this?

```
[[window contentView] setHidden:YES];
```

And conversely...

```
[[window contentView] setHidden:NO];
```

That's certainly less tedious and complicated. :D

Comment: That might actually be a good idea than going one by one and hiding all of them. This would just hide the entire contentView. Thanks :)

Comment: But this is also hiding my main window content, I mean main screen is blank now :(

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya Perhaps another approach is better suited for your needs.

Comment: @trudyscousin Could u suggest the way please, actually I know there is an approach of taking a view on window, keeping on adding our views to that, then to navigate to main window, we can simply hide that view. But I am trying to add everything to window's content view to imitate the behaviour of ios navigation in mac...please suggest me how I can remove all content views from main window, i.e. jump directly to main window when main menu button is clicked?? thanks :)

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya Not here. Present your question as a question, not a comment.

Comment: @trudyscousin [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532827/hide-content-view-of-nsapplication-window) is the question Mr.Trudy, please help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(NSView* view in [[window contentView] subviews])
{
    [view setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude. One of those things that are just handy snippets to keep :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is a NSView:

```
//Hide views
for (NSView *view in [[myWindow contentView] subviews]) {
   [view setHidden:YES];
}


//Show views
for (NSView *view in [[myWindow contentView] subviews]) {
   [view setHidden:NO];
}
```

You will probably need to call a setNeedsDisplay somewhere.

*EDITED*
Sorry, been working in Ruby all day. Edited to make it Objective C :)

Untested, but should get you started.

Comment: What are those `end` statements? That's not Objective-C.