# Hide content view of NSApplication window in order to navigate to main screen

Tags: cocoa, hidden, nswindow, setcontentview

Initially I have my own setup on application main window, i.e. an image view(for background) and on it I have a set of buttons. Now when user taps on the buttons, respective lesson is launched, i.e. user is being navigated to the corresponding screen, i.e. I add the view to window's content view....

```
[self.window.contentView addSubview:self.lessonScreen.view];
```

Actually I know there is an approach of taking a view(custom view) on window, keeping on adding our views to that(for navigation). Then for navigating to main screen(window), we can simply hide that view. But I am following the approach of adding views through window's content view.

However the views get added fine, but I am not able to navigate to home screen, I tried various ways and the below is one of the method I followed:

```
[[window contentView] setHidden:YES];
```

Now what happens is the window becomes blank, the main view also vanishes.

I also tried to enumerate views in windows content view subviews and remove the same, but I am getting a crash and more over the same blank screen appears in this case too :(

I have also gone through questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066193/remove-nswindow-content-view) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756277/hide-show-all-objects-in-a-nswindow-cocoa) which didn't solve my problem.

Can some one please suggest me a way to remove content view from main window in order to jump to my main screen as I have main menu button for user navigation.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want replace one view with another?

Comment: Initially we have window(home screen),right? on that I have my view setup, i.e. an image view with background, buttons etc. Now when the buttons are pressed, I am navigating to the respective view by accessing windows content view add subview property. This is how we keep on doing, now I have a main menu button underneath the view, if I click on that I should go to the main menu(main window) screen, i.e. remove all content view added

Comment: As a warning, do not spam comments on unrelated questions asking people to answer your question. I just removed a pile of these, as they were being flagged across the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My basic foundation was not proper, previously I didn't create my own class to handle main view controller. That's the reason why things went weird.

Just create our main menu view by creating our own NSViewController class, then add the same as our window's content view by adding in `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` method of our appDelegate file, i.e.:

```
self.mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.contentView = _mainViewController.view;
```

Now that we have started adding our own views to window's content view, in order to navigate to home screen, we need not hide the content view, instead assign our home view as the window's content view:

```
-(IBAction)topicButton:(id)sender
{
    [AppDelegate sharedInstance].mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[AppDelegate sharedInstance].window setContentView:[AppDelegate sharedInstanceofAppDelegate].mainViewController.view];
}
```

**Note:** Here [AppDelegate sharedInstance] is the instance of our app delegate class, i.e.:

```
+(AppDelegate *)sharedInstance
{
    if (!sharedAppDelegate) {
        sharedAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    }
    return sharedAppDelegate;
}
```

That's it, we can now navigate the user to home screen when ever topic or main menu button's clicked :)

Hope it helps, thanks to one and all for the concern :)

Answer (score 0):

Connect this method to the appropriate button or menu item

```
- (IBAction)deliteAllSubviews:(id)sender {

    NSArray* views = [[window contentView]subviews];

    for (NSView* view in views) {   
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: This will remove all subviews of window.contentView. Just compare you view objects(you want to remove) and use removefrom superview.

Comment: Crash: <__NSArrayM: 0x608000242820> was mutated while being enumerated.

Comment: Add NSMutableArray *arrtoDelete = [views mutablecopy];    before your for loop and try again

Comment: @Student As mentioned before, facing blank screen issue, i.e. I am not able to view my home screen(main window)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56683/discussion-between-student-and-eshwar-chaitanya).

Comment: @Student Pls come to chat room :)